# Does shared_ptr allocate when constructed from raw pointer?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, pool, lock-free

As far as I understand shared_ptr it contains a pointer to a control block which contains the raw pointer strong count and weak count.

I'm in a situation where I need lock-free allocation, so I can allocate a raw pointer from the pool allocated memory and then make a unique pointer with a custom deleter to put it back in the pool, so far so good.

In the case of a shared_ptr however if I construct a shared pointer with one of these raw pointers and custom allocators does it allocate the control block at that point?

If it does is there a way to provide the memory for the control block in a lock-free way?

Comment: What lock are you trying to avoid?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz [Recommended reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46356957/560648)

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Thanks. That suggests, as I suspected, that there is nothing to do here. Your platform already does the right thing if it's not junk.

Comment: That's not how I read it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the case of a shared_ptr however if I construct a shared pointer with one of these raw pointers and custom allocators does it allocate the control block at that point?

Yes.

> If it does is there a way to provide the memory for the control block in a lock-free way?

`shared_ptr`'s constructor has overloads that accept a custom allocator.

Refer to [some `shared_ptr` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).

*(I'm not entirely clear [whether the deleter will also be allocated by your custom allocator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58932991/560648).)*

Comment: Does this also allocate the memory for the type erased deleter?

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe That's an excellent question! It, er, doesn't seem to be specified :O

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe I've [asked this separately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58932991/560648). Will edit into this answer if I get an acceptable response!

Comment: Hehehe looks like a popular question so far