# Is a shared_ptr's deleter stored in memory allocated by the custom allocator?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, shared-ptr, allocator

Say I have a `shared_ptr` with a custom allocator *and* a custom deleter.

I can't find anything in the standard that talks about where the deleter should be stored: it doesn't say that the custom allocator will be used for the deleter's memory, and it doesn't say that it *won't* be.

Is this unspecified or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 12):

util.smartptr.shared.const/9 in C++ 11:

> Effects: Constructs a shared_ptr object that owns the object p and the deleter d. The second and fourth constructors shall use a copy of a to allocate memory for internal use.

The second and fourth constructors have these prototypes:

```cpp
template<class Y, class D, class A> shared_ptr(Y* p, D d, A a);
template<class D, class A> shared_ptr(nullptr_t p, D d, A a);
```

In the latest draft, util.smartptr.shared.const/10 is equivalent for our purpose:

> Effects: Constructs a shared_­ptr object that owns the object p and the deleter d. When T is not an array type, the first and second constructors enable shared_­from_­this with p. The second and fourth constructors shall use a copy of a to allocate memory for internal use. If an exception is thrown, d(p) is called.

So the allocator is used if there is a need to allocate it in allocated memory. Based on the current standard and at relevant defect reports, allocation is not mandatory but assumed by the committee.

- Although the interface of `shared_ptr` allows an implementation where there is never a control block and all `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` are put in a linked list, there is no such implementation in practice. Additionally, the wording has been modified assuming, for instance, that the `use_count` is shared.
- The deleter is required to only move constructible. Thus, it is not possible to have several copies in the `shared_ptr`.

One can imagine an implementation which puts the deleter in a specially designed `shared_ptr` and moves it when it the special `shared_ptr` is deleted. While the implementation seems conformant, it is also strange, especially since a control block may be needed for the use count (it is perhaps possible but even weirder to do the same thing with the use count).

Relevant DRs I found: [545](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#545), [575](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#575), [2434](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2434) (which acknowledge that all implementations are using a control block and seem to imply that multi-threading constraints somewhat mandate it), [2802](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2802) (which requires that the deleter only move constructible and thus prevents implementation where the deleter is copied between several `shared_ptr`'s).

Comment: "to allocate memory for internal use"  What if the implementation isn't going to allocate memory for internal use to begin with?  It can use a member.

Comment: @L.F. It can't, the interface does not allow for that.

Comment: Theoretically, it can still use some kind of "small deleter optimization", right?

Comment: What is weird is that I can't find anything about using the same allocator (copy of `a`) to _deallocate_ that memory. Which would imply some storage of that copy of `a`. There is no information about it in [util.smartptr.shared.dest].

Comment: @L.F. It could be but I'm not sure.  I'd have to think more about the interaction with `shared_from_this`.  It would for sure not be practical, the facts that the interface expose `use_count` and the standard evolved to remove the note that use_count can be inefficient, that the only use of the allocator is to allocate a control block, and so on hint strongly that there is a control block and putting some information out of control block when one is available seems weird.

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica, I agree that's weird.  I can't find it either.

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica, I wonder if in util.smartptr.shared/1: "The shared_­ptr class template stores a pointer, usually obtained via new. shared_­ptr implements semantics of shared ownership; the last remaining owner of the pointer is responsible for destroying the object, or otherwise releasing the resources associated with the stored pointer." the _releasing the resources associated with the stored pointer_ is not intended for that. But the control block should survive as well until the last weak pointer is deleted.

Answer (score 5):

From [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) we have:

> The control block is a dynamically-allocated object that holds:

- either a pointer to the managed object or the managed object itself;
- **the deleter (type-erased);**
- the allocator (type-erased);
- the number of shared_ptrs that own the managed object;
- the number of weak_ptrs that refer to the managed object.

And from [std::allocate_shared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared) we get:

```
template< class T, class Alloc, class... Args >
shared_ptr<T> allocate_shared( const Alloc& alloc, Args&&... args );
```

> Constructs an object of type T and wraps it in a std::shared_ptr [...] in order to use **one allocation for both the control block** of the shared pointer and the T object.

So it looks like [std::allocate_shared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared) should allocate the `deleter` with your `Alloc`.

EDIT: And from `n4810` §20.11.3.6 Creation [util.smartptr.shared.create]

> 1 The common requirements that apply to all `make_shared`, **`allocate_shared`**, `make_shared_default_init`,
>   and `allocate_shared_default_init` overloads, unless specified otherwise, are described below.
>
> [...]
>
> 7 Remarks:
>   (7.1) — **Implementations should perform no more than one memory allocation. [Note: This provides
>   efficiency equivalent to an intrusive smart pointer. —end note]**

[Emphasis all mine]

So the standard is saying that `std::allocate_shared` *should* use `Alloc` for the control block.

Comment: I'm sorry by cppreference is not a normative text. It's a great resource, but not necessarily for [tag:language-lawyer] questions.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Totally agree - looked through the latest standard and couldn't find anything so went with cppreference.

Comment: @PaulEvans, http://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.shared.create

Comment: However, this is talking about `make_shared`, not the constructors themselves.  Still, I can use a member for small deleters.

Comment: @L.F. It's saying that implementations should use one memory allocation for the control block of the shared pointer and the `T` object. Since it's allocating for the `T` object, `Alloc` must be used for `std::allocate_shared`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica cppreference is good in general, and bloated than the std text, and excellent for understanding the variations in a feature over versions. But it's very poor and incomplete re: memory model and atomics.

Comment: @PaulEvans But that doesn't mean that `make_shared` has to be implemented in terms of the publicly available constructors, right?

Comment: @L.F. I'm referring to `std::allocate_shared`, `std::make_shared` just so happens to be in the same section. I read it as saying: `std::allocate_shared` should allocate memory for the control block (and therefore the deleter) and the `T` object's memory in one `Alloc` allocation.

Comment: @PaulEvans Sorry, both of my comments were meant to say `allocate_shared` instead of `make_shared`.  What if I don't use `allocate_shared` and use the constructor directly?

Comment: @L.F. That's where I'm finding it very difficult to get anything hard from the standard.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is unspecified.

Here's the specification of the relevant constructors: [[util.smartptr.shared.const]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/util.smartptr.shared.const#10)

> ```
> template<class Y, class D> shared_ptr(Y* p, D d);
> template<class Y, class D, class A> shared_ptr(Y* p, D d, A a);
> template <class D> shared_ptr(nullptr_t p, D d);
> template <class D, class A> shared_ptr(nullptr_t p, D d, A a);
> ```
>
> *Effects:* Constructs a `shared_­ptr` object that owns the object `p` and the deleter `d`. When `T` is not an array type, the first and
>   second constructors enable `shared_­from_­this` with `p`. The second
>   and fourth constructors **shall use a copy of `a` to allocate memory
>   for internal use**. If an exception is thrown, `d(p)` is called.

Now, my interpretation is that when the implementation needs memory for internal use, it does so by using `a`.  It doesn't mean that the implementation has to use this memory to place everything.  For example, suppose that there's this weird implementation:

```
template <typename T>
class shared_ptr : /* ... */ {
    // ...
    std::aligned_storage<16> _Small_deleter;
    // ...
public:
    // ...
    template <class _D, class _A>
    shared_ptr(nullptr_t, _D __d, _A __a) // for example
        : _Allocator_base{__a}
    {
        if constexpr (sizeof(_D) <= 16)
            _Construct_at(&_Small_deleter, std::move(__d));
        else
            // use 'a' to allocate storage for the deleter
    }
// ...
};
```

Does this implementation "use a copy of `a` to allocate memory for internal use"?  Yes, it does.  It never allocates memory except by using `a`.  There are many problems with this naive implementation, but let's say that it switches to using allocators in all but the simplest case in which the `shared_ptr` is constructed directly from a pointer and is never copied or moved or otherwise referenced and there are no other complications.  The point is, just because we fail to imagine a valid implementation doesn't by itself prove that it cannot theoretically exist.  I am not saying that such an implementation can actually be found in the real world, just that the standard doesn't seem to be actively prohibiting it.

Comment: IMO your `shared_ptr` for small types allocates memory on the stack. And so does not meet standard requirements

Comment: @bartop It doesn’t “allocate” any memory on the stack.  _Smaller_deleter is unconditionally a part of the representation of a shared_ptr.  Calling a constructor on this space doesn’t mean allocating anything.  Otherwise, even holding a pointer to the control block counts as “allocating memory”, right? :-)

Comment: But the deleter is not required to be copyable, so how would this work?

Comment: @NicolBolas Umm ...  Use `std::move(__d)`, and fall back to `allocate` when copy is required.