# Lock-free "decrement if not zero"

Tags: c++, thread-safety, atomic, lock-free

I'm currently reinventing the wheel of a thread pool in C++. I've eliminated almost all locks from the code, except for multiple instances of the following construct:

```
std::atomic_size_t counter;

void produce() {
    ++counter;
}

void try_consume() {
    if (counter != 0) {
        --counter;
        // ...
    }
    else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So, I need a thread-safe lock-free version of this function:

```
bool take(std::atomic_size_t& value) {
    if (value != 0) {
        --value;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

There is one solution that I know of: use `boost::lockfree::queue<std::monostate>`, where `pop()` does the job. Is there any better/faster solution?

Comment: Why not use a traditional compare and swap loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construct you're implementing is a counting lock, or [counting semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)). Use one from a library that has a `trylock` version instead of rolling your own, so you can get optimized OS-supported sleep / wakeup. Or do you always have useful work to do if the `trylock` (aka `take`) fails?

Note that you can avoid using any traditional locks while implementing your own, but "lock free" is a technical term with a different meaning than lockless.  A consumer almost by definition can't be [lock-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm#Lock-freedom) in the computer-science sense, because it can be stuck waiting forever if the producer thread(s) are blocked.  Related: [Lock-free Progress Guarantees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45907210/lock-free-progress-guarantees)

---

CAS is good.  Just make sure that your function doesn't run `compare_exchange_weak` at all if it sees the counter already 0 with a pure load (typically with `memory_order_relaxed`).  You don't want your CPU hammering on the location while other threads are trying to increment it so your thread will see a non-zero value.

Another option is a signed counter, and change the compare to `>= 0`.  Check for overshoot in the result of `fetch_add(-1)`, and if so correct it.  (Threads that see the counter as temporarily negative just see it "locked").  But this is typically not better than a CAS retry loop; failed CAS is rare unless contention is *very* high.  And extra atomic ops to correct overshoot will probably cost about as much (or more) than CAS retries.

Comment: Semaphores are exactly what I need. I ended up with using `boost::interprocess::interprocess_semaphore` and `try_wait`.