# Is there a "not equal compare and exchange" or "fetch add on not equal" for C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

Or any way to implement?

Let's have an atomic:

```
std::atomic<int> val;
val = 0;
```

Now I want to update val only if val is not zero.

```
if (val != 0) {
    // <- Caveat if val becomes 0 here by another thread.
    val.fetch_sub(1);  
}
```

So maybe:

```
int not_expected = 0;
val.hypothetical_not_compare_exchange_strong(not_expected, val - 1);
```

Actually the above also will not work because val may get updated between `val - 1` and the hypothetical function.

Maybe this:

```
int old_val = val;
if (old_val == 0) {
    // val is zero, don't update val. some other logic.
} else {

    int new_val = old_val - 1;
    bool could_update = val.compare_exchange_strong(old_val, new_val);
    if (!could_update) {
        // repeat the above steps again.
    } 
}
```

Edit:

`val` is a counter variable, not related to destruction of an object though. It's supposed to be an unsigned (since count can never be negative).

From thread A: if type 2 is sent out, type 1 cannot be sent out unless type 2 counter is 0.

```
while(true) {
    if counter_1 < max_type_1_limit && counter_2 == 0 && somelogic:
        send_request_type1();
        counter_1++;

    if some logic && counter_2 == 0:
        send_request_type2();
        counter_2++;
}
```

thread B & C: handle response:

```
if counter_1 > 0:
     counter_1-- 
     // (provided that after this counter_1 doesn't reduce to negative)
else 
     counter_2--
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to "decrement the value if it's not zero"?

Comment: Yes. There are other threads decrementing/incrementing and doing logic based on that.

Comment: Is this meant as a reference count, so when the number hits zero, the object is destroyed? Or are you trying to implement something like a semaphore, where the count defines how many things are waiting on the object (for example)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lock-free "decrement if not zero"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47650290/lock-free-decrement-if-not-zero)

Comment: @MatsPetersson I have updated the usage of val. It's a counter variable, I require two. counter_1 and counter_2 as mentioned in the edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general way to implement not available atomic operations is using a [CAS loop](http://preshing.com/20150402/you-can-do-any-kind-of-atomic-read-modify-write-operation/); in your case it would look like this:

```
/// atomically decrements %val if it's not zero; returns true if it
/// decremented, false otherwise
bool decrement_if_nonzero(std::atomic_int &val) {
    int old_value = val.load();
    do {
        if(old_value == 0) return false;
    } while(!val.compare_exchange_weak(old_value, old_value-1));
    return true;
}
```

So, Thread B & C would be:

```
if(!decrement_if_nonzero(counter_1)) {
    counter_2--
}
```

and thread A could use plain atomic loads/increments - thread A is the only one who increments the counters, so its check about `counter_1` being under a certain threshold will always hold, regardless of what thread B and C do.

The only "strange" thing I see is the `counter_2` fixup logic - in thread B & C it's decremented without checking for zero, while in thread A it's incremented only if it's zero - it looks like a bug. Did you mean to clamp it to zero in thread B/C as well?

---

That being said, atomics are great and all, but are trickier to get right, so if I were implementing this kind of logic I'd start out with a mutex, and then move to atomics if profiling pointed out that the mutex was a bottleneck.