# Backoff strategy for producers/consumers when a lock-free queue is full/empty?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, producer-consumer, lock-free

Assume a producer-consumer scenario. I have used a lock-free implementation of a fixed-capacity queue, so that:

1. The number of items that can be held in the queue is limited.
2. Producers/consumers can push/pop items to/from the queue directly without holding any lock.

Now, I'm considering how to synchronize the producers and consumers, so that producers are not busy try-pushing to a full queue, and consumers are not busy try-popping from an empty queue.

I thought about condition variable at first. But it seems to destroy the whole purpose of using a lock-free queue implementation.

Is polling (with interval) the only sensible way to go with a lock-free queue?

Comment: Capacitated is not a word.  I think you mean "fixed capacity".

Comment: Most real implementations optimistically try the lock-free way for a few iterations of busy waiting before using a fall-back mechanism like going to sleep.  And probably setting an atomic flag so the first producer to push something will know to wake up a consumer.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45907210/lock-free-progress-guarantees for links to (and discussion about) a real-world implementation (liblfds) of a multi-producer multi-consumer lock-free queue with a power-of-2 fixed capacity.  I haven't looked at its full/empty backoff code, but it's sophisticated.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the hint. Now I know where to look into :)