# Is boost::lockfree::queue (in multithreaded program) lockable?

Tags: c++, boost, queue, lock-free, lockless

I am working on a program where, 2+ (gstreamer) *boost::* threads and same number of *boost::* threads of a dummy application are simultaneously using **a queue**. Now this queue is used for **synchronization** between tasks of **gstreamer thread with** its corresponding **dummy application thread**.

The queue is an EVENT queue: where the EVENT is a structure

```
typedef struct EVENT{
    EVENT_TYPE Ev_Type;  // EVENT_TYPE is enum of Events
    EVENT_DATA Ev_Data;  // EVENT_DATA is union of data to be stored for that event
}Event_;
```

Upon googling, I came across these 2 options for queue: *lockfree::queue* & *lockfree::spsc_queue*, suggesting that `lockfree::queues` are used for multithreaded applications.

> CONFUSION: Why the name lockFREE? is it suggesting cannot be (mutex) locked?
>
> Also see [this example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/lockfree/examples.html), it says *"boost::lockfree::queue is not lockfree"*
>
> Mind=blown...

Well, I then tried following the example [(above link)](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/lockfree/examples.html) and implement this queue

```
class Foo {
protected:
    boost::lockfree::queue<EVENT> mqSttEventQueue;
public:
    unsigned int SetEventIntoQueue(EVENT *psEvent);
};
```

And its definition as:

```
unsigned int Foo::SetEventIntoQueue(EVENT *psEvent) {
    if(mqSttEventQueue.push(*psEvent)){
         //notify that event is in queue;
    }
}
```

This is compiled successfully. But I am completely running in the dark here.

**QUESTIONS:**

- Why the example declares the queue as

  `boost::lockfree::queue<int> queue(128);`

what is that **128** there for? Is it saying the queue size is 128 (bytes/items)? Is `queue<int>` declaring the type of data in the queue?

- Why didnt it work for my program

  `boost::lockfree::queue<EVENT> mqSttEventQueue(128);`

If I declare it like this, it gets compilation error as

> ```
> error: expected identifier before numeric constant
>
> boost::lockfree::queue<EVENT> mqSttEventQueue(128);
>                                               ^~~
> ```

PS:- I am really not sure what title to put here...Edit it if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why the name lockFREE? is it suggesting cannot be (mutex) locked?

Of course anything *can* be locked; you put the mutex outside the data structure and have every thread that touches the data structure use it.

`boost::lockfree::queue` provides `unsynchronized_pop` and `unsynchronized_push` for use in cases where you've ensured that only one thread can be accessing the queue.

**But the main purpose of `lockfree::queue` and of lockless algorithms / data structures is that they *don't* need to be locked: multiple threads can safely write and/or read at the same time.**

---

**"lock free" has 2 meanings in programming**, leading to potentially confusing but true statements like "this lockless algorithm is not lock-free".

- **Casual usage: synonym for lockless** -  implemented without mutexes, using atomic loads, stores, and RMW operations like CAS or `std::atomic::atomic_fetch_add`.  See for example [An Introduction to Lock-Free Programming](https://preshing.com/20120612/an-introduction-to-lock-free-programming/) (Jeff Preshing).  And maybe [What every systems programmer should know about concurrency](https://assets.bitbashing.io/papers/concurrency-primer.pdf).

  `std::shared_ptr` uses lockless atomic operations to manage its control block.  C++11 [`std::atomic<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) provides lockless primitives for custom algorithms.  See [stdatomic](/questions/tagged/stdatomic).  Normally in C++11, unsynchronized access to the same variable by multiple threads is undefined behaviour.  (Unless they're all read-only.)  But `std::atomic` gives you well-defined behaviour, with your choice of sequential-consistency, acquire/release, or relaxed memory ordering.
- **Technical computer-science meaning: a thread sleeping forever or being killed won't block the rest of the threads**.  i.e. guaranteed forward progress for the program as a whole (at least one thread).  (Wait-free is when threads never have to retry).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm.  A CAS retry loop is a classic example of lock-free but not wait-free.  Wait-free is stuff like RCU (read-copy-update) read threads, or depending on definitions, a `atomic_fetch_add` on hardware that implements it as a primitive (e.g. x86 `xadd`), not in terms of an LL/SC or CAS retry loop.

**Most lockless multi-reader / multi-writer queues are not lock-free in the technical sense.**  Usually they use a circular buffer, and a writer will "claim" an entry somehow (fixing its order in the queue). but it can't be read until the writer *finishes* writing to the entry itself.

See [Lock-free Progress Guarantees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45907210/lock-free-progress-guarantees) for an example with analysis of its possible blocking behaviour.  A writer atomically increments a write-index, then writes data into the array entry.  If the writer sleeps between doing those things, other writers can fill up the later entries while readers are stuck waiting for that claimed but not written entry.  (I haven't looked at `boost::lockfree::queue<T>`, but presumably it's similar<sup>1</sup>.)

**In practice performance is excellent with very low contention between writers and readers.  But in theory a writer could block at just the wrong moment and stall the whole queue.**

---

Footnote 1:  The other plausible option for a queue is a a linked list.  In that case you can fully construct a new node and then attempt to CAS it into the list.  So if you succeed at adding it, then other threads can read it right away because you have its pointers set correctly.

But the reclaim problem (safely freeing memory that other threads might be reading to see if another reader has already claimed them) is extremely thorny outside of garbage-collected languages / environments.  (e.g. Java)

---

> `boost::lockfree::queue<int> queue(128);`   Why 128?

That's the queue (max) size, in entries.  Of `int` in this case, because you used `queue<int>`, duh.  As mentioned above, most lockless queues use a fixed size circular buffer.  It can't realloc and copy like std::vector when it needs to grow, because other threads can be reading it simultaneously.

As documented [in the manual](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html) (the first google hit for `boost::lockfree::queue`), the `explicit queue(size_type)` constructor takes a size.

You could also bake the capacity into the type, by using it as a template parameter.  (So the capacity becomes a compile-time constant everywhere that uses the queue, not just in places that can do constant-propagation from the constructor call.)

The class apparently doesn't enforce / require a power-of-2 size, so a template size parameter could maybe optimize significantly better by letting `% capacity` operations compile into an AND with a mask instead of a division.

Comment: side note: SO's `[lock-free]` tag should probably be a synonym of `[lockless]`. 
 But currently [tag:lock-free] has so many more questions than [tag:lockless] that it won't allow proposing a synonym in that direction.  Or maybe it's just wishful thinking that we can popularize a term that doesn't have a more specific technical meaning in the same subject area and  bludgeon people into using it.