# Lockless queue using std::atomic

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, queue, stdatomic

I wish to create a lockless queue using `std::atomic`.
Here's my probably not so good first attempt at trying to do so:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class atomic_queue
{
public:
    using value_type = T;
private:
    struct node
    {
        value_type m_value;
        node* m_next;
        node* m_prev;

        node(const value_type& value) :
            m_value(value),
            m_next(nullptr),
            m_prev(nullptr) {}
    };
private:
    std::atomic<node*> m_head = nullptr;
    std::atomic<node*> m_tail = nullptr;
public:
    void push(const value_type& value)
    {
        auto new_node = new node(value);

        node* tmp = nullptr;
        if (m_tail.compare_exchange_strong(tmp, new_node))
        {
            m_head.store(new_node, std::memory_order_relaxed);
            return;
        }

        node* old_tail;
        do {
            old_tail = m_tail;
            new_node->m_prev = old_tail;
        } while (!m_tail.compare_exchange_strong(old_tail, new_node));
        new_node->m_prev->m_next = new_node;
    }

    void pop()
    {
        if (m_head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }

        node* tmp = nullptr;
        node* head = m_head;
        if (m_tail.compare_exchange_strong(head, tmp))
        {
            m_head.store(tmp, std::memory_order_relaxed);
            return;
        }

        node* old_head;
        do {
            old_head = m_head;
        } while (m_head && !m_head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head, old_head->m_next));
        if (old_head)
        {
            delete old_head;
        }
    }

    bool empty()
    {
        return m_head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == nullptr;
    }

    value_type& front()
    {
        node* head = m_head.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        return head->m_value;
    }
};
```

Something to note here is that I store `m_prev` on `node` so that I could update the `m_next` of `m_tail` after successful `push` without actually doing so via `m_tail` incase it was changed already by another thread. So even if another thread got to `push` a new value already, the current thread would still link what it saw as the `m_tail`'s `m_next` to the new node.

Now there're a few things that are not really thread-safe as far as I can tell and which I can't really think of a good way to solve these problems:

Let's assume `thread1` `pop`s from the queue the one and only item then we go inside the following if statement:

```cpp
        node* tmp = nullptr;
        node* head = m_head;
        if (m_tail.compare_exchange_strong(head, tmp))
        {
            // Now thread2 kicks in
            m_head.store(tmp, std::memory_order_relaxed);
            return;
        }
```

And let's assume `thread2` kicks in at the marked spot to `push` a new value to the queue the the following statement will be executed:

```cpp
        node* tmp = nullptr;
        if (m_tail.compare_exchange_strong(tmp, new_node))
        {
            m_head.store(new_node, std::memory_order_relaxed);
            return;
        }
```

and let us assume it finished it's `push`ing without `thread1` continuing and only then `thread1` continues, then `thread1` will execute:

```cpp
        m_head.store(tmp, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        return;
```

and will basically undo `thread2`'s `push` by setting `m_head` to `nullptr`.
As far as I can understand memory orders can't help me in this scenario so I'm not sure what my options are?

Another problematic scenario is that let's assume we have 2 reader threads `thread3` and `thread4`
doing the same job:

```cpp
    while (true)
    {
        if (!q.empty())
        {
            int v = q.front();
            q.pop();
            std::stringstream stream;
            stream << "thread_3/4: " << v << '\n';
            std::cout << stream.str();
        }
    }
```

And let us assume the queue is of size 1, so both of them could see that the queue is not empty and get a reference to the front data and then pop the element and print the same result. 
It seems to me that locking would help in this scenario, but I do no wish to use locking and also I do not wish the reading threads to care about synchronization problems because the interface itself should be the one responsible, but since `front` and `pop` are independent I don't see a good way to handle this. 
Also there's the problem that `front` might access `nullptr`, so even here I'm not sure how to handle this. I can make the interface return a raw pointer, or `std::optional` but both solutions seems not correct in my eyes so would love to hear opinions on what should be done here.

Also, I'm not sure if I could go away with cheaper methods other than CAS, I know I could go with unique slot approach where each thread get an index into a fixed array by using `fetch_add` on atomic of type `std::atomic<int> slot` and so each thread pushes to the queue to a unique index, but I don't like this approach since it makes the limitation of a fixed size queue. On the other hand using `new` and `delete` is probably not the fastest thing either, I could use a pool allocator of sort, but then I would have to make sure it's synchronized as-well and that's a new level of pain.

I'm not even sure these are all the problems, these are the problems that I could spot with my implementation, I'm sure I didn't think of everything (or maybe I did?), anyway would love to hear yours thoughts on the described problems and maybe ways to overcome them.

Comment: In my eyes, invoking a memory allocation in `push` kinda defeats any gains that might be made by going lock-free.

Comment: ^ Because underlying calls to `malloc` are protected by a mutex.

Comment: The deallocation problem (for multi-threaded code) is very hard to solve efficiently in a language without garbage collection.  That's why many good lockless queue implementations use power-of-2 sized circular buffers.  e.g. have a look at the one described in [Lock-free Progress Guarantees](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45907210)

Comment: @paddy yea it's on of my points in the post

Comment: @paddy Every half decent memory manager nowadays uses thread local pools. So even though they are usually not fully lock-free, lock contention due to memory allocations are mostly a thing of the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your implementation, some of which you have already identified correctly.

1. The race between the two `m_head.store` operations after the CAS on `m_tail`
2. This loop potentially suffers from the [ABA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem):

```
  do {
        old_head = m_head;
  } while (m_head && !m_head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head, old_head->m_next));
```

3. After removing a node in `pop`, you immediately `delete` it, but at that time another thread might still have a reference to it and *access* it (e.g. another thread in pop), resulting in a use-after-free. (This is also known as the memory reclamation problem.)
   **Explanation:** Suppose two threads are currently inside `pop` and have read the same value into `old_head`. The first thread goes ahead, performs the CAS on `m_head` and in the next step immediately deletes `old_head`. Only now the second thread continues with its own attempt to update `m_head`, using `old_head->m_next` as new value. That means thread two *derefences a pointer to the just deleted node*.
4. Your design requires two separate function calls to pop an item from the queue and get its value.

It is inherently difficult to design lock-free or even lock-less algorithms. The issues 2. and 3. can both be resolved by using a memory reclamation scheme. Issue 4. is usually avoided by not using a `front` operation, but instead have `pop` return the item (either directly via `std::optional`, or via a `try_pop` version that takes an out-parameter by reference and returns a bool that indicates whether the operation was successful).

Either way, I would recommend to go with one of the established lock-free algorithms like the [Michael-Scott-Queue](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/u/scott/papers/1996_PODC_queues.pdf). Unfortunately, if you decide to implement that algorithm, you still have to take care of the memory reclamation problem.

I can refer you to my [Xenium](https://github.com/mpoeter/xenium/) which provides not only an implementation of the Michael-Scott-Queue, but also several memory reclamation schemes in case you still want to experiment a bit yourself, but want to avoid the hassle with safe memory reclamation.

---

A memory reclamation scheme is an algorithm to solve the memory reclamation problem. There are a lot of proposed solutions to solve the problem of safe memory reclamation, like hazard pointers or epoch based reclamation, but every scheme has its drawbacks. That's why the memory reclamation problem is still seen as the current most difficult open problem in shared memory concurrency. For more details I can refer you to my master's thesis [Effective Memory Reclamation forLock-Free Data Structures in C++](https://repositum.tuwien.at/retrieve/8679). It not only explains the memory reclamation problem and a large number of proposed reclamation schemes, but also discusses my implementation of some of these schemes, based on a generic interface. [Xenium](https://github.com/mpoeter/xenium/) builds on that work.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable feedback.
Before going into known implementation and libraries I would want to try and solve all these problems first as part of a learning path.
Do you have any idea on how to solve the race between the `m_head.store` it's one of the things I've noted and I'm not really sure how and you haven't gave suggestions regarding this point. About point number 2, you're correct, thanks for spotting this out. About point number three I  think it's not correct what you said, I still have a problem in my code where I reassign `old_head = m_head` in the loop by myself

Comment: but I shouldn't be doing it since `compare_exchange_strong` should update `old_head` in the case of failure, so no 2 threads will leave the `pop` loop with the same `old_head` so I think deleting it is ok after removing the redundant assignment in the loop, correct me if I'm wrong please.
And could you please elaborate on what's memory reclamation scheme and how I can leverage it to solve these problems?

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide more details for your open questions. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Oh, I forgot. Issue 1. is inherently a result of your design choice, and I don't see an easy way to fix it. Designing lock-free algorithms takes _a lot_ of practice. As I said, I recommend to check out the Michael-Scott-Queue, and if you want to learn, try to understand the algorithm and its underlying ideas, and perhaps try to implement it yourself (in a first simple version you can simply ignore memory reclamation an just leak nodes).