# lock-free queue to count prime numbers in c performance

Tags: c, multithreading, linked-list, primes, lock-free

I try to use multi-threads with lock-free queues to do the best performance to count prime numbers ***without editing the naive prime check function*** and in a maximum of only 1.8MB of RAM space.

On the first try, I did a multi-thread but I had a problem with the memory, so I moved to a linked list to reduce memory, and after I read about the lock-free queue.

but I stuck with my attempt to improve the performance.

In the code, I get a very large amount of numbers and I need to count how many prime numbers from stdin.

My question is: how I can reduce the time to best performance?

Second Attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

#define MAX_ARRAY_SIZE 500000 

int array[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];
atomic_int shared_counter = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(0);
int total_primes = 0;

// Function to check if a number is prime
bool isPrime(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// Worker function to find prime numbers in the array
void *worker(void *arg)
{
    int local_counter = 0;
    int index;

    while ((index = atomic_fetch_sub(&shared_counter, 1)) > 0)
    {
        if (isPrime(array[index]))
        {
            local_counter++;
        }
    }

    return (void *)local_counter;
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    pthread_t threads[4];

    // Read numbers from stdin and store them in the array until end of file or array full
    int array_size = 0;
    while (scanf("%d", &num) != EOF && array_size < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE)
    {
        array[array_size++] = num;
    }

    atomic_store(&shared_counter, array_size);

    // Create worker threads
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    { // Create 4 threads, you may adjust this number based on your system
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, worker, NULL);
    }

    // Join worker threads and accumulate prime counts
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        void *result;
        pthread_join(threads[i], &result);
        total_primes += (int)result;
    }

    printf("%d total primes.\n", total_primes);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no question in your post. Edit it to ask a specific question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil my  question is how to improve without modify the function of the Prime

Comment: As discussed in comments on the previous version of your question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77969241/lock-free-queue-to-count-primes-numbers-from-stdin-in-c), handing out small batches of numbers instead of one at a time reduces queue overhead.  Or chunks of ASCII data for parallel parsing if you want.

Comment: Doing all the I/O and creating a potentially-giant linked list before starting any threads seems to defeat the purpose of a lock-free queue.  If you're going to do that, it would be much more efficient to create an array even if you end up having to resize it as it grows.  Then hand out chunks of it to threads with OpenMP as 
Jérôme Richard suggested, or with a queue of start/end ranges. Seems like a regression vs. your previous question, where overlap of I/O & parsing with prime-checking work was possible.

Comment: As you maybe found, deallocation is a problem for a lock-free linked list in a non-garbage-collected environment.  That's one reason to use a fixed-size array, like the one from liblfds discussed in [Lock-free Progress Guarantees in a circular buffer queue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45907210) which takes some measures to reduce contention between readers and writers.  Again, the queue entries can be structs of 8 or 16 ints.  (Or 7 or 15 or something to make the circular queue struct size a power of 2 including its sequence number)

Comment: *so I moved to a linked list to reduce memory,* - Huh?  A linked list needs 16 bytes per `int` (assuming `sizeof(void*) == 8` and `alignof(void*) == 8`), plus malloc bookkeeping overhead, so a linked list instead of an array probably costs you about 8x as much memory as an array to read in all the numbers before doing any I/O.  Also, a circular buffer lock-free queue could easily be small, like 1 or 2x 4K pages is probably fine, whether you store a single int per queue entry or 7.

Comment: Your entire approach is wrong. Instead of testing every integer for primality, you should be *generating* the primes. Look up the Sieve of Eratosthenes. No threads and no queues, and zillions of times as fast,

Comment: @user207421: It is a stated constraint of the problem that the primality testing may not be changed. The problem is an exercise in multithreading, and the primality testing is an artificial workload. It is not an exercise in finding prime numbers.

Comment: @ATB Note that `i*i` in  `for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++) {` overflows (UB) when `n` is a large prime near `INT_MAX`.  Better as `for (int i = 2; i <= n/i; i++) {`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: It is a stated constraint of the problem it be done “without editing the naive prime check function.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil True about “without editing the naïve prime check function.”, yet `for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++) {` remains an overflow risk - something useful to note to OP.

Comment: _I stuck with my attempt to improve the performance._  - well, how do you measure performance and what makes you say that you are stuck with your 2nd attempt? What are the performance estimates for your 1st and 2nd attempts, and the source code to reproduce?

Answer (score 2):

Your particular problem of counting prime numbers in an array using multiple threads has a minimalist solution which doesn't require anything more than one shared atomic counter.

The algorithm:

1. Load the integers into a plain integer array.
2. Create a signed atomic counter initialized with the number of elements in the array.
3. Create the worker threads sharing the array of integers and the atomic counter. Each worker thread maintains its own non-atomic prime number count.
4. Each worker thread does `fetch_sub(shared_counter, 1) - 1` to get the index of the next array element to check for whether it is a prime number.
5. If the index is non-negative, check whether array element at that index is a prime number and update the prime number counter. Goto 4.
6. Otherwise, if the index is negative, the worker thread terminates, returning its non-shared prime number count (cast to `void*`).
7. The main thread joins the worker threads and sums up their prime number count return values.

This way, your worker threads contend only on `fetch_sub` of the shared counter. Contending on one shared atomic counter is as simple and efficient solution as it ever gets.

To minimise contention to absolute bare minimum, each worker thread may want to grab not the next 1 index to process, but, say, next 1,000,000 indexes to process.

---

The ideas I want to convey here are:

1. One shared atomic counter can be enough to spread task processing between multiple worker threads, and that is as cheap and efficient as it gets. No fancy multi-producer-multi-consumer data structures may be necessary.
2. Be mindful to not bottleneck on contending updating the shared counter too often. Increasing the chunk size is a simple way to minimize this contention. My arbitrary 1,000,000 chunk size above may not be ideal for this particular problem.

Comment: 1 million is too big a chunk size, IMO.  16 elements would be reasonable minimum chunk size, but 64 to 256 ints could be good choices for big arrays if there are very big imbalances in work per chunk, like some runs of even numbers and some runs of large primes.  32 `int` elements is a pair of cache lines; if the array is aligned by 128 bytes (32 ints), or at least if `&array[shared_position]` is aligned, then each cache line of data is only read by one core (including L2 adjacent-line prefetch), making better use of memory traffic (and L3 footprint in Zen or multi-socket systems with NUMA L3)

Comment: @Fredrik This solution is quite useful in Python. Place the shared atomic index of the next task to process into shared memory, along with an array for all task results. And `fork` worker processes right there in the middle of the function. Each worker process grabs the index of the next task to process from the shared atomic counter, processes that task as the main thread would do, stores the result into the shared result array. No serialization or inefficient multi-process IPC is involved here, unlike when using `multiprocessing` module. It is high-level description, details are omitted.

Comment: @PeterCordes You are quite right. Chunk size of 1 results in perfect load balancing, and the concern here is to avoid contending on the shared counter more often then necessary. For relatively long-running tasks (relative to the cost of `fetch_add`) that is a non-issue. But checking for prime numbers is super-quick for even numbers, hence my arbitrary chunk size of 1e6 to avoid saturating buses with MESI RFO messages for `fetch_add`.

Comment: Yup, true, long runs of even numbers could go blazing fast in the best case for overall speed, worst case for contention.  So filter those out during parsing.  Or better, *before* parsing, since 10 is a multiple of 2 so we only need to check the low bit of the ASCII code for the LSD.  Although that would mean finding the end of each digit-string instead of just converting on the fly.  Perhaps if parsing with SIMD, some additional filtering to remove evens and left-pack could be thrown in.  Quickly finding the next whitespace and checking the previous char could allow better ILP for conversion.

Comment: Still, multiples of 3 or 5 won't take long either, and contention is worse the more cores you have.  You want a chunk size such that `chunks = n/size` is more than the number of cores by maybe a factor of 10 so big imbalances in time per chunk don't leave some cores idle.  So the appropriate chunk size grows with n_threads, and total problem size for high efficiency grows quadratically?

Comment: Maybe hand out 50 to 75% of the work in the first set of chunks, then have a smaller chunk size to the few threads that finish early can start on the remainder with low contention, and you get increasing contention as you get closer to the end with more threads and maybe an ever-shrinking adaptive chunk size?  Or hierarchical pools of remaining work for small groups of threads to divvy up, only communicating with other groups when they're out of work, if you want to get fancy.

Comment: The OP says they only want to use up to 1.8 MiB, so for large inputs like 1 million `int32_t` they already need to do something other than reading all the input first, because that's 4 MiB for an array, probably 4x to 8x that for their linked list of separately-malloced nodes on a 64-bit machine.  So huge chunk sizes are a non-starter; a big-array solution needs to be tuned to work for problem sizes up to about 500k `int`s.  (Of course, limited storage is the motivating factor for using an actual SPMC queue to still be able to read an unbounded size of input.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I can never match your numerical analysis diligence, Peter. The ideas I wanted to convey is a) one shared atomic counter can be enough to spread task processing between multiple worker threads, and that is as cheap and efficient as it gets, no fancy multi-producer-multi-consumer data structures are necessary; b) be mindful to not bottleneck on contending updating the shared counter too often and increasing the chunk size is a simple way to minimize this contention. My arbitrary 1e6 chunk may not be ideal for this particular problem.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I did edit my attempt and when i use very huge list of numbers its not calculate them all.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin you mention creating an array but what size the array if i have a long long long long list of numbers like 10Million of numbers how i can store them all in an array? look please the edit of the question above in my attempt

Comment: @ATB You can reserve a huge chunk of a 64-bit address space with mmap and rely on demand paging to back it with RAM only for the parts you use. Or use an atomic circular buffer, e.g. https://github.com/max0x7ba/atomic_queue

Comment: @ATB Now that you rewrote your question to implement my answer, improving performance of your original code by an order of magnitude, my answer no longer makes sense. That's rather unkind and disingenuous of you, in my opinion.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I didn't mean to hurt, I just want to learn and try to do my best,
I will return the code and the edit I didn't want to hurt or make you angry, can you help me I don't understand how to do what you said

Comment: @ATB You may like to code and provide the benchmarks that measure performance of your first and second attempts, so that you yourself can see and appreciate the difference. Talking about performance without benchmarks and measurements is meaningless.